# What exactly is innerHTML, and how does document.write work?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("script").length + " Scripts");
        console.log(document.head.innerHTML);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What would you expect the console.log to contain? I hope you come to one of the two outcomes that I would expect: `4 Scripts` and either the two existing or all four script tags shown in the head's innerHTML (`document.write` could as well write to the body, so one could expect the script tags to be injected as children of the body).

The thing is that, in Chrome and IE11, the first script tag added via document.write is shown in the head's `innerHTML`, but the second isn't, and the DOM query result is `3 Scripts`.

Could anyone please elaborate?

Comment: @mplungjan upvotes don't always indicate appropriateness of a question (didn't vote)

Comment: I set script.js to x=1, script2.js to y=1 and script3.js to z=1 and I get y is undefined

Comment: @mplungjan Me too. `script2.js` is in innerHTML, `y` is undefined, but a `console.log` inside `script2.js` is printed into console!

Comment: FWIW I got curious and posted a link in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22603409#22603409). Seems safe to assume that the behaviour when doing that is undefined.

Comment: Use `script.addEventListener('load', function () { console.log('Now the script should be loaded and ready to go') })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving it a chance to render works in Chrome:

In the script I have script.js: x=1, script2.js: y=1 and script3.js:z=1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("after 1",x);
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"><\/script>');
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"><\/script>');
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("script").length + " Scripts");
          console.log(document.head.innerHTML);
          console.log("after 3",x,y,z)
        },100); // the milliseconds MAY need to be higher over the net
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Result:

```
4 Scripts

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"><\/script>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("script").length + " Scripts");
      console.log(document.head.innerHTML);
      console.log("after 3",x,y,z)
      },10)
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>

after 3 1 1 1
```

Comment: Side note. When I changed script 3 to `z=1+y` I got 1,1,2 as expected

Comment: I think it's better to use the actual "onload" event of the script elements instead of an arbitrary delay.

Answer (score 1):

Using `document.write()` is the old and [bad way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) of doing things, you should be using the DOM :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Child 1
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'script2.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        //Child 2
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'script3.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("script").length + " Scripts");
        console.log(document.head.innerHTML);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It returns `4 Scripts`

Comment: `document.write` is what the sencha touch 2 "testing" microloader does :(

Comment: Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation of the `3` count is that the scripts added via document.write are executed synchronously. So:

1. Script engine executes the script block that contains document.write

   - Script engine adds the first script to DOM.
   - Script engine does not add the second script to DOM -- it must wait for the first script to download and execute. After all, it is possible for the first script to do a `document.write("<!--");`
   - Script engine returns the count 3
2. Script engine downloads the first script and executes it.
3. Script engine adds the second script to the DOM, downloads it and executes it.

Keep in mind that JavaScript is single threaded. This prevents the execution of script tags generated by document.write until the script that generates script tags is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Is this because you're writing a script tag inside another script tag and ultimately creating invalid markup (i could be wrong, but my theory matches what you are seeing)

```
1---> <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

2---> <script type="text/javascript">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js">
       </script>

3---> <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js">
          </script>
      </script>
```

maybe?!

**UPDATE**

After a little playing I agree with @mplungjan, it's a timing issue. This works as expected. Scripts count is now obvs 5

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("script").length + " Scripts");
        console.log(document.head.innerHTML);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The escaping of the end tag USED to make it valid

Comment: @mplungjan doesn't it still?

Comment: It still makes it valid. But see my answer for the reason for the inconsitency (PS: I did not downvote)

Comment: If that was true, then almost **any** use of `document.write()` would generate invalid code. The entire script element is parsed before the script is executed. `document.write()` will put content immediately after the script element. (Or if you mean that the string `<script>` inside the script would cause a problem, then you're still wrong since script elements are defined (in HTML 4 terms) as containing CDATA so only end tags matter (and in HTML 5 only script end tags matter) to the HTML parser.

Comment: Could the down voter please explain why. And yes @Quentin, I was wrong in my first answer.